# Linux Setuid special permission flag with read/write

Tags: files, permissions, setuid

Does the **setuid** is only applicable for execute file(only applicable with executable flags) ?

How it will affect other permission(read/write) of same file !

Eg:- If the the actual file permission is **4711**, non-owner user can't read it. *Why its not elevating the owner permission 4711 and allow others to read the content.*

Comment: Because allowing others to read it is 04.

Comment: Yes, but my doubt is since i set, setuid(4000), can't the file make user of owner permission(7 [ rws ~> rwx ]). There by allow the other to read/write/execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-owner can't read the file because setuid and setgid only affect the effective permissions *when the file is executed*; otherwise, the file permissions are used. Here's an example program to try:

**readme.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *f;
  int i;
  char c;

  if(argc>1) {
    f=fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    for(i=1; i++<100;) {
      c=getc(f);
      printf("%x%s", (int)c, i%50?" ":"\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
  }
}
```

Compile it and change its permissions as someone other than who you want to test with (I used `root`):

```
# gcc -Wall -o readme readme.c
# chown root:root readme
# chmod ug+s,o-rw readme
```

Verify the permissions and try reading the file as your test user:

```
erik ~ $ ls -la readme
-rwsr-s--x 1 root root 8064 May  4 12:05 readme
erik ~ $ cat readme
cat: readme: Permission denied
```

Now try running the program and have it read itself:

```
erik ~ $ ./readme readme
7f 45 4c 46 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 3e 0 1 0 0 0 fffffff0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 40 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 40 18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 40 0 38 0 9 0 40 0 1d 0 1c 0 6 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 40 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 40 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 40 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 fffffff8 1 0
```

You'll see it had no problems, because the effective permissions changed to a user *with* read permissions.

Why does this happen? Several reasons come to mind. First, there's no real need for anyone to have read permissions to run an executable because the kernel (which loads the program) has full permissions to do anything already. You only need to have read permissions if you want to view the contents of the executable file, usually so you can copy the file. It's possible, to name some possible examples, that the executable has sensitive data that users shouldn't see (which is strongly discouraged, but has happened!) or the system is using this as a defence in depth to prevent people from finding exploits.